# Problem with Permission on Google Cloud IAM for non Gmail Users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I was trying to attach permission to user with a company email like email@example.com, but it wasn't working.

First, I started with creating the role and adding its permissions, then I navigated to the IAM section to attach the role to the user, in Principal I added the email as mentioned which is email@example.com, then i selected the custom role, but unfortuatily it didn't work
The user I added his email was trying to find the project, it doesn't show in his panel as it isn't added, refreshing the console home, but nothing is working.
I came back again to add a predefined role like Viewer, but it also didn't work.

After that, I tried to add the same roles to a gmail account like email@gmail.com, It worked.

I searched a lot to understand what is happening, but I cannot find a logical explaination.

After that, I tried to copy the project URL from my window "admin window", like the following "https://console.cloud.google.com/welcome/new?project=########" and pasted this url in the user window, so the user can check whether he can access the project or not, and it's worked.

Now he can access the Project, and everything is fine.

How can I avoid this from hapenning again? and why this is happening? is this normal?

Comment: Is the user `email@example.com` part of your Google Cloud organization? If not, you cannot use foreign principals from other authorization systems. The first and second parts of your post do not make sense regarding each other. Edit and provide more clarity.